# Division by zero ? (In newton iteration method)

Tags: python, optimization, zero

I'm doing a newton iteration to find T_a. Everything seems fine in the code except in one the very first definitions. 
My rho(T_a) returns a division by zero (it assumes that T_a is zero while it's just a variable. If I change the T_a in the equation to something like 100, everything runs smoothly.
Any idea why it's returning a division by zero?

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import pylab
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

#     THETA NOTATION:
#pi/2: substellar point
#-pi/2: antistellar point
#0: terminators


#define constants used in equations:
alb = 0.2 #constant albedo
F = 866 #J/s*m**2
R = 287.0 #J/K*kg
U = 5.0 #m/s
C_p = 1000 #J/K*kg
C_d = 0.0015
p1 = 10**4
p2 = 10**5.0
p3 = 10**6.0 #Pa
sig = 5.67*10**-8.0 #J/s*m**2*K**4 #Stefan-Boltzmann cst


def rho(T_a):
    p1=10000.0
    R=287.0 #J/K*kg
    return (p1/(T_a*R))

def a(T_a):
    U = 5 #m/s
    C_p = 1000 #J/K*kg
    C_d = 0.0015
    return rho(T_a)*C_p*C_d*U




#################################################
##### PART 2 : check integrals equality
#################################################


#define the RHS and LHS of integral equality

def LHS(theta):
    return (1-alb)*F*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta)


#define the result of each integral

Left = integrate.quad(lambda theta: LHS(theta), 0, pi/2)[0]


#define a function 1-(result LHS/result RHS)  >>> We look for the zero of this


x0=130.0 #guess a value for T_a
#T_a = 131.0

#Python way of solving for the zero of the function

#Define T_g in function of T_a, have RHS(T_a) return T_g**4 etc, have             result_RHS(T_a) return int.RHS(T_a),
#have func(T_a) return result_LHS/result_RHS


def T_g(T_a,theta):
    return np.roots(array([(sig),0,0,(a(T_a)),((-a(T_a)*T_a)-LHS(theta))]))[3]

def RHS(theta,T_a):
    return sig*T_g(T_a,theta)**4*np.cos(theta)

def result_RHS(T_a,theta):
    return integrate.quad(lambda theta: RHS(T_a,theta), -pi/2, pi/2)[0]

def function(T_a,theta):
    return 1-((Left/result_RHS(T_a,theta)))

theta = np.arange(-pi/2, pi/2, pi/20)

T_a_0 = scipy.optimize.newton(function,x0,fprime=None,args=(theta,),tol=    (10**-5),maxiter=50000)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/FindT_a.py", line 85, in <module>
    T_a_0 = scipy.optimize.newton(function,x0,fprime=None,args=(theta,),tol=(10**-5),maxiter=50000)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py", line 120, in newton
    q0 = func(*((p0,) + args))
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/FindT_a.py", line 81, in function
    return 1-((Left/result_RHS(T_a,theta)))
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/FindT_a.py", line 78, in result_RHS
    return integrate.quad(lambda theta: RHS(T_a,theta), -pi/2, pi/2)[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 247, in quad
    retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 312, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/FindT_a.py", line 78, in <lambda>
    return integrate.quad(lambda theta: RHS(T_a,theta), -pi/2, pi/2)[0]
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/FindT_a.py", line 75, in RHS
    return sig*T_g(T_a,theta)**4*np.cos(theta)
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/FindT_a.py", line 72, in T_g
    return np.roots(array([(sig),0,0,(a(T_a)),((-a(T_a)*T_a)-LHS(theta))]))[3]
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/FindT_a.py", line 38, in a
    return rho(T_a)*C_p*C_d*U
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/FindT_a.py", line 32, in rho
    return (p1/(T_a*R))
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RHS` function is defined slightly differently to all the others, in that it has `theta` first and `T_a` as its second argument:

```
def RHS(theta,T_a):
    return sig*T_g(T_a,theta)**4*np.cos(theta)
```

I think that's why you passed the arguments in the wrong order here:

```
lambda theta: RHS(T_a,theta)
```

Get them in the right order and you should be OK.

As a side-note, some of your imports look like they could cause weird bugs:

```
from numpy import *
from math import *
```

Numpy and the `math` module have at least a few function names in common, like `sqrt`. It's safer to just do `import math` and `import numpy as np`, and access the functions through the module name. Otherwise what happens when you call `sqrt` could change depending on the order you do your imports in.

Answer (score 0):

You reversed your parameters:

In `result_RHS` you call: `RHS(T_a,theta)`, but the parameter definition of `RHS` is `def RHS(theta,T_a)`

Swap those in in the definition and the error no longer occurs. Your definition should look like this:

```
def RHS(T_a, theta)
```